# const char* if() comparison with "SRAD" returns false

Tags: c++, string, char

Here is my code:

```
const TiXmlAttribute* pAttr = pElem->FirstAttribute();
const char* name = pAttr->Name(); // attribute name
const char* value = pAttr->Value(); // attribute value
float _D = 0.0;

if("SRAD" == name)  // returns false here, but name is indeed "SRAD"
{
    _D = atof(value);
}
```

The problem is the name is "SRAD", but the if condition returns false. Anyone educate me why? Thanks.

Comment: You are comparing pointers. Compare strings instead.

Comment: Care to post some code here perhaps?

Comment: No. Look it up. It is trivial and there are twenty million duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This compares the pointers, not the contents.

You need to use `strcmp`:

```
if(strcmp("SRAD", name) == 0)
```

Comment: I will take yours as answer because I can set name and value same data type.

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing pointer values, not string contents. The pointers will (almost certainly) not be equal, even if the strings are.

Either use `std::string`, for which `==` and other operators compare the string contents:

```
#include <string>

std::string name = pAttr->Name();
if("SRAD" == name) // works as expected
```

or delve into the C library

```
#include <cstring>

if (std::strcmp(name, "SRAD") == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you even write the following way

```
if ( "A" == "A" ) { /* do something */ }
```

the result of the condition can be either true or false. The problem is that in this condition string literals that have types of array `char[2]` are converted to pointers to their first elements. And the compiler may store equal string literals either in diferrent extents of memory or store only one representation of the same string literals.

Thus in this statement

```
if("SRAD" == name)
```

you are comparing addresses of the first elements of string literal "SRAD" and of the array pointed to by pointer name.

You should use standard C function `strcmp` declared in header `<string.h>`. For example

```
if( strcmp( "SRAD", name ) == 0 ) /* ...*/;
```